# Getting process command line arguments from minidump

Tags: windows-7, bsod, minidumps

I am investigating a BSOD and I'd like to know more about the process that caused the problem. I can open the minidump in WinDbg which gives a lot of information about the crash. However the one piece of information I haven't been able to get is the command line arguments of the process that caused the crash.

Does anyone know if it is something that can be extracted from a crash dump?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) and see if it displays what you want.

Comment: BlueScreenView didn't help but I found the solution - see answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The information I was looking for is stored in the [process environment block (PEB)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Environment_Block). In WinDbg the *!peb* command displays a formatted view of the PEB. This view contains an entry for the command line that was used to start the process.

Comment: Note that this won't always work, because the PEB is not always one of the things that's captured in the minidump, except for the current process.

Comment: What if the process is svchost? I m meaning since there are lot of svchost, I need to not get the command line of all processes but the command line or pid of the one which caused the crash.